# Is it possible to destructure the `self` argument of a method?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I am trying to find a way to destructure the `self` argument of a method.  According to a [GitHub comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/12566#issuecomment-37353339):

> Per today's meeting, we have a different plan to make self arguments destructurable. With universal function-call syntax (UFCS #11938) there will not be any distinction between static methods and instance methods - they will both be 'associated functions'. At that point any function who's first argument is the self type will be callable with method syntax, and `self`, `&self`, and `&mut self` are just sugar for i.e. `self: &Self`, and destructuring on the self argument can be done as normal by not using the self-sugar.

I wrote the following code, but it does not work as I expected in that all three print functions can be used as a method.

```
struct Vector {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    z: i32,
}

impl Vector {
    fn print1(self: &Self) {
        println!("{} {} {}", self.x, self.y, self.z);
    }

    // destructure self argument
    fn print2(&Vector{x, y, z}: &Self) {
        println!("{} {} {}", x, y, z);
    }

    // use another name for the first argument
    fn print3(this: &Self) {
        println!("{} {} {}", this.x, this.y, this.z);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = Vector{x: 1, y: 2, z: 3};

    Vector::print1(&v); // work
    v.print1();         // work
    Vector::print2(&v); // work
    v.print2();         // not work
    Vector::print3(&v); // work
    v.print3();         // not work
}
```

`print3()` was just used to test if it is possible to use a name other than `self` for the first argument of a method.

It gives this compile error:

```
error: no method named `print2` found for type `Vector` in the current scope
  --> 1.rs:27:7
   |
27 |     v.print2();         // not work
   |       ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: found the following associated functions; to be used as methods, functions must have a `self` parameter
note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl for the type `Vector`
  --> 1.rs:12:5
   |
12 |       fn print2(&Vector{x, y, z}: &Self) {
   |  _____^ starting here...
13 | |         println!("{} {} {}", x, y, z);
14 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here

error: no method named `print3` found for type `Vector` in the current scope
  --> 1.rs:29:7
   |
29 |     v.print3();         // not work
   |       ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: found the following associated functions; to be used as methods, functions must have a `self` parameter
note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl for the type `Vector`
  --> 1.rs:16:5
   |
16 |       fn print3(this: &Self) {
   |  _____^ starting here...
17 | |         println!("{} {} {}", this.x, this.y, this.z);
18 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here
```

It seems that `print2()` and `print3()` are not identified as methods of `Vector`.

1. How to destructure the `self` argument of a method?
2. According to the comment, the name `self` is just sugar. Does it mean that a name other than `self` can be used for the first argument of a method?

Comment: The first parameter must be named `self`, as stated in the note. `self` is a keyword.

Comment: @kennytm He says that `self` is just a sugar, so does it mean that the first argument's name is not necessary to be  `self`?

Comment: @Laurence: The excerpt you are looking is dated February 2014, Rust 1.0 got out on May 15, 2015. Beware when looking too far in Rust history, as things changed a lot until 1.0; it may very well be that the comment you are basing your question on is simply obsolete.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, it is a relatively old post, but I didn't find other more recent posts about this issue, so I put it here..

Comment: @Laurence: Oh don't worry; it's clearly an appropriate question for SO and hopefully you'll get a definite answer.

Comment: @Laurence while the first argument must be `self`, `&self`, or `&mut self` for it to be a method, you can destructure inside the function, like so: `let &Vector{x, y, z} = self;`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This was originally intended to be possible with the Universal Function Calls, but is backwards incompatible, because it would mean that `fn foo(bar: &Self)` would suddenly be equivalent to `fn foo(self: &Self)`, which can break method calls due to new methods appearing suddenly.

Full rationale in [this github issue comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16293#issuecomment-185906859)

You can destructure the explicit `self` parameter with a `let` binding in the function body:

```
let &Vector { x, y, z } = self;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  impl Vector {        
    fn print(&self) {
      // destructure self argument
      let Vector { x, y, z } = &self;
      println!("{} {} {}", x, y, z);
    }
  }
```